# transparent bits in pygame mask are black instead of being transparent

Tags: python, pygame-surface, python-3.10, pygame2

I have a program where it fills in the bits of a mask that are overlapped from another mask, but when I blit the mask of the overlapping bits onto the screen, the transparent bits are fully black for some reason? The program works as intended and I've tried converting the surface for the overlapping bits to per pixel alpha but the transparent bits are black

[example gif](https://gfycat.com/emptyyellowishgreathornedowl)

```py
import pygame
import sprites

SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH = 800, 800
running = True

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = sprites.Block((100, 100))
block2 = sprites.Block((100, 100))
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group(block2)

block2.rect.topleft = 150, 150
block2.image.fill((0, 255, 0))

while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()

    screen.fill((100, 100, 100))
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player.move(screen.get_rect())
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)
    blocks.draw(screen)

    for block in blocks:
        offset = (player.rect.x - block.rect.x, player.rect.y - block.rect.y)
        colliding_bits = player.mask.overlap_mask(block.mask, offset)
        colliding_bits_image = colliding_bits.to_surface(setcolor=(0, 255, 0))

        screen.blit(colliding_bits_image, block.rect)

    clock.tick(144)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

code containing the sprite classes:

```py
import pygame


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("flappy_bird.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

        self.speed = 1

        super().__init__()

    def move(self, screen_rect):
        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)
        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)
        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)

        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `unsetcolor` attribute to the `to_surface` method and removed the line `blocks.draw(screen)` and it seems to produce the desired result :

```
from math import fabs
import pygame
import sprites

SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH = 800, 800
running = True

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = sprites.Block((100, 100))
block2 = sprites.Block((100, 100))
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group(block2)

block2.rect.topleft = 150, 150
block2.image.fill((0, 255, 0))

while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()

    screen.fill((100, 100, 100))
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player.move(screen.get_rect())
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)

    for block in blocks:
        offset = (player.rect.x - block.rect.x, player.rect.y - block.rect.y)
        colliding_bits = player.mask.overlap_mask(block.mask, offset)
        colliding_bits_image = colliding_bits.to_surface(setcolor=(0, 255, 0, 255), unsetcolor=(0, 0, 0, 0))

        screen.blit(colliding_bits_image, block.rect)

    clock.tick(144)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: thanks it worked, just had to blit the actual image over the transparent mask surface though

Comment: Glad I could be of help! Good continuation in your project ;)